# Spark Scala: Split each line between multiple RDDs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a file on HDFS in the form of:

```
61,139,75
63,140,77
64,129,82
68,128,56
71,140,47
73,141,38
75,128,59
64,129,61
64,129,80
64,129,99
```

I create an RDD from it and and zip the elements with their index:

```
val data = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:54310/usrp/sample.txt")
val points = data.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(',').map(_.toDouble)))
val indexed = points.zipWithIndex()
val indexedData = indexed.map{case (value,index) => (index,value)}
```

Now I need to create `rdd1` with the index and the first two elements of each line. Then need to create `rdd2` with the index and third element of each row. I am new to Scala, can you please help me with how to do this ?

This does not work since `y` is not of type `Vector` but `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector`

```
val rdd1 = indexedData.map{case (x,y) => (x,y.take(2))}
```

Basically how to get he first two elements of such a vector ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `DenseVector`'s `unapply` method to get the underlying `Array[Double]` in your pattern-matching, and then call `take`/`drop` on the Array, re-wrapping it with a Vector:

```
val rdd1 = indexedData.map { case (i, DenseVector(arr)) => (i, Vectors.dense(arr.take(2))) }
val rdd2 = indexedData.map { case (i, DenseVector(arr)) => (i, Vectors.dense(arr.drop(2))) }
```

As you can see - this means the original `DenseVector` you created isn't really that useful, so if you're not going to use `indexedData` anywhere else, it might be better to create `indexedData` as a `RDD[(Long, Array[Double])]` in the first place:

```
val points = data.map(s => s.split(',').map(_.toDouble))
val indexedData: RDD[(Long, Array[Double])] = points.zipWithIndex().map(_.swap)

val rdd1 = indexedData.mapValues(arr => Vectors.dense(arr.take(2)))
val rdd2 = indexedData.mapValues(arr => Vectors.dense(arr.drop(2)))
```

Last tip: you probably want to call `.cache()` on `indexedData` before scanning it twice to create`rdd1` and `rdd2` - otherwise the file will be loaded and parsed twice.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the above output by following the below steps:

### Original Data:

```
indexedData.foreach(println)
(0,[61.0,139.0,75.0])
(1,[63.0,140.0,77.0])
(2,[64.0,129.0,82.0])
(3,[68.0,128.0,56.0])
(4,[71.0,140.0,47.0])
(5,[73.0,141.0,38.0])
(6,[75.0,128.0,59.0])
(7,[64.0,129.0,61.0])
(8,[64.0,129.0,80.0])
(9,[64.0,129.0,99.0])
```

### RRD1 Data:

Having index along with first two elements of each line.

```
val rdd1 = indexedData.map{case (x,y) => (x, (y.toArray(0), y.toArray(1)))}
rdd1.foreach(println)
(0,(61.0,139.0))
(1,(63.0,140.0))
(2,(64.0,129.0))
(3,(68.0,128.0))
(4,(71.0,140.0))
(5,(73.0,141.0))
(6,(75.0,128.0))
(7,(64.0,129.0))
(8,(64.0,129.0))
(9,(64.0,129.0))
```

### RRD2 Data:

Having index along with third element of row.

```
val rdd2 = indexedData.map{case (x,y) => (x, y.toArray(2))}
rdd2.foreach(println)
(0,75.0)
(1,77.0)
(2,82.0)
(3,56.0)
(4,47.0)
(5,38.0)
(6,59.0)
(7,61.0)
(8,80.0)
(9,99.0)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I needed a vector instead of array.